# Invertibility of covariance matrix when number of training examples are lesser than number of features

Tags: self-study, outliers, covariance-matrix

I was trying to study an outlier detection algorithm and realized that in case we use a multinomial Gaussian distribution to model data then the invertibility of Covariance matrix ($\sum$) is essential.

However, in case the number of training examples $(m)$ is lesser than the number of features $(n)$ why does $\sum$ become non-invertible?

Answer (score 0):

Covariance matrix becomes non-invertible when $m < n$ due to a property of linear subspace.

> Theorem 2: Every spanning set S of a vector space V must contain at least as many elements as any linearly independent set of vectors from V.

Reference: [Wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_span)

Clearly, in order to span the feature space of order $\Re^{n}$ we need at least $n$ training examples.